# Adding 2 sql table columns value to one C# property, using Dapper.NET

Tags: c#, .net, dapper

I have a class `Department`.

`Deparment` has one property called `Address`.

I have a SQL table called `Deparment`.

This `Department` has 2 columns `Address1` and `Address2`.

I use Dapper.net and would like to put the two SQL table columns into the one property of my class.

How ? Thank!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do:

```
public class Department {
    public string Address1 {get;set;}
    public string Address2 {get;set;}

    public string Address {
        get { return Address1 + Environment.NewLine + Address2; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using this for "Read-Only". How would you expect your ORM to write the data back to the database ?

If it is read-only, instead of querying the table directly, you could wrap it in a view.

```
CREATE VIEW DepartmentView
(
    SELECT Address1 + ', ' + Address2 as Address FROM Department
)
```

and then just map the view instead.